# javascript regex does not match the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble with this regex. It's not matching at the beginning of the string.

Why doesn't this regex match `roll` or `rolls`?

```
/^[rR]olls?/
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's my code:

```
var cleaned = connection.escape(move).toLowerCase();
var sql = "SELECT n FROM things WHERE n LIKE ";
if(cleaned.match(/^rolls?/))
{
  sql += "\"%roll%\"";
  connection.query(sql, handleErr);
}
```

Comment: It does match those strings. `/^[rR]olls?/.test("roll")` returns `true`. Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Seems to match for me, [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vL1sM7)

Comment: It [does](http://regex101.com/r/kF4lF2). Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly something wrong in your code.  The regex matches.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Cool. Thanks. For some reason it wasn't matching on http://regex101.com/

Comment: Should I be using match? "roll".match(/^[rR]olls?/);

Comment: Sure if you actually want the match, if you want to validate use `test`

Comment: You can use the `i` modifier here for case insensitive matching. `/^rolls?/i`

Comment: I updated my original post with the code I'm using. I'm still not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my code was in the wrong order. I found out that connection.escape().length was returning a length greater than move.length. The escape() returns a string with some extra characters. I fixed it by reordering my code to compare the regex first and then sanitize the input before appending it to the query.

**FIXED**

```
var sql = "SELECT n FROM things WHERE n LIKE ";
if(move.match(/^rolls?/))
{
  sql += connection.escape(move).toLowerCase();
  connection.query(sql, handleErr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ACbh/1/).

You're testing String.match(pattern) which returns the part of the string which matches -- [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

What you want to be testing is pattern.test(String) -- [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

```
var cleaned = connection.escape(move).toLowerCase();
var sql = "SELECT n FROM things WHERE n LIKE ";
var pattern = /^rolls/i;
if (pattern.test(cleaned))
{
  sql += "\"%roll%\"";
  connection.query(sql, handleErr);
}
```